# ReactJs connect 2 child components

Tags: javascript, angular, reactjs

If in Angular 2 is possible to connect two child components with each other how is  it manageable in react js?

Comment: Generally you can pass data between 2 sibling components by using the parent's state or by using a state management library such as redux.

Answer (score 0):

A) You can use Redux or Flux to keep a single state for the whole application, which you will be able to access from any component that you decide to connect with this state, called the Store.

You can read more about this in https://github.com/reduxjs/redux.

B) If both components are siblings, and the state you are trying to share is not something that you would care about in the rest of the application, you can pass the state from the parent to both children, as props, and also pass a function that allows the children to set the parent's state.

For example:

```
class Parent extends Component {
  state = {
    something: '',
  }

  changeSomething = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      something: e.target.value,
    })
  }

  render() {
    const { something, changeSomething } = this.state;
    return(
      <div>
        <ChildrenA
          something={something}
          changeSomething={changeSomething}
        >
        <ChildrenB
          something={something}
          changeSomething={changeSomething}
        >
      </div>
    );
}
```

Now both children have access to `this.props.something` and `this.props.changeSomething` and they can both change the parent's state and both will see the changes.

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks a lot, @andresmechali